# How can I start a coroutine at the same time as executing a regular function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I made a Reload() function that checks the current mag and ammo of a weapon and then reloads it, and I also want play sounds while I reload and so I made an IEnumerator to match the sounds with my animation. But now when I call both of those the Reload() function executes then the audio plays, I want both to happen at the same time.

Here is my script in the Update function:
(the ws.getWeapon is just to check what weapon the player has equiped to play the corresponding animation and audio)

```
if (CurrentMag <= 0 && CurrentAmmo > 0 || Input.GetKeyDown("r") && CurrentMag < MagCap && CurrentAmmo > 0)
        {
            if (ws.getWeapon() == 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ReloadAudio(0));
                animator.Play("PistolReload");
            }
            else if (ws.getWeapon() == 1)
            {
                animator.Play("AK12_Reload");
            }

            Reload();
        }
```

Here is my Reload function:

```
void Reload()
    {
        if(CurrentMag <= 0 && CurrentAmmo > 0)
        {
            CurrentMag = 0;
            MagCount.text = CurrentMag.ToString();
            ReloadTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (ReloadTimer <= 0)
            {
                ReloadTimer = ReloadTime;
                if (CurrentAmmo <= MagCap)
                {
                    CurrentMag = CurrentAmmo;
                    CurrentAmmo = 0;
                    AmmoCount.text = CurrentAmmo.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentMag = MagCap;
                    CurrentAmmo -= (MagCap - OldMag);
                    AmmoCount.text = CurrentAmmo.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my ReloadAudio IEnumerator:

```
IEnumerator ReloadAudio(int ID)
    {
        if (ID == 0)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("G18_MagOut");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.47f);
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("G18_MagIn");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("G18_CockBack");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Coroutines run at the same time. The code doesnt stop and run that code. So where you start it. It is now running that coroutine and continuing through your first chunk of code

Comment: But I'm trying to execute a IEnumerator and a void function at the same time, because right now if run my code and reload, the Reload function is gonna happen and my gun is going to reload but only once the Reload function is done executing then the IEnumerator that plays the audio is gonna start executing even though I put StartCoroutine before Reload()

Comment: It just seems like it because the play doesnt wait to play the whole animation so that reload gets to the end like 1ms later. It might take that long for it to find your audiomanager.